# Django: Mark as Read "Notifications"

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a school project. Right now any user can ask a question.

In order to notify all the users when any users asks a question I've created a new app & notifying them through the simple 'view' whenever a question is asked. But it's just plain notifications yet.

How can I mark them read once a user opens the Notification tab? Just like on social networks!

Comment: if you want to consider a notification 'read' when the user opens the page, then you need to put your logic in the call to the page. look up the user from the session, and update the notification object then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`ContentType`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType) to make a dynamic notifications fo any models. This snippet below is an example how to implement the ***notification system***;

**1. in your `models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class ContentTypeToGetModel(object):

    """
    requires fields:
        - content_type: FK(ContentType)
        - object_id: PositiveIntegerField()
    """

    def get_related_object(self):
        """
        return the related object of content_type.
        eg: <Question: Holisticly grow synergistic best practices>
        """
        # This should return an error: MultipleObjectsReturned
        # return self.content_type.get_object_for_this_type()
        # So, i handle it with this one:
        model_class = self.content_type.model_class()
        return model_class.objects.get(id=self.object_id)

    @property
    def _model_name(self):
        """
        return lowercase of model name.
        eg: `question`, `answer`
        """
        return self.get_related_object()._meta.model_name


class Notification(models.Model, ContentTypeToGetModel):
    # sender = models.ForeignKey(
    #    User, related_name='notification_sender')

    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='notification_receiver')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, related_name='notifications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Object id'))
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('reply', _('a reply')),
        ('comment', _('a comment')),
        ('message', _('a message'))
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        _('Status'), max_length=20,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='comment')

    is_read = models.BooleanField(
        _('Is read?'), default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        title = _('%(receiver)s have a %(status)s in the %(model)s:%(id)s')
        return title % {'receiver': self.receiver.username, 'status': self.status,
                        'model': self._model_name, 'id': self.object_id}

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('notifications')
        ordering = ['-created']
```

**2. in your `views.py`**

```
from django.views.generic import (ListView, DetailView)
from yourapp.models import Notification


class NotificationListView(ListView):
    model = Notification
    context_object_name = 'notifications'
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'yourapp/notifications.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        notifications = self.model.objects.filter(receiver=self.request.user)

        # mark as reads if `user` is visit on this page.
        notifications.update(is_read=True)
        return notifications
```

**3. in your `yourapp/notifications.html`**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% for notif in notifications %}
  {{ notif }}

  {# for specific is like below #}
  {# `specific_model_name` eg: `comment`, `message`, `post` #}
  {% if notif._model_name == 'specific_model_name' %}
    {# do_stuff #}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

> So, when I creat that notifications?
>   eg: when the other user send a comment to `receiver` on this post.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def send_a_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            #instance.sender = request.user
            ...
            instance.save()

            receiver = User.objects.filter(email=instance.email).first()
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model='comment')

            notif = Notification.objects.create(
                receiver=receiver,
                #sender=request.user,
                content_type=content_type,
                object_id=instance.id,
                status='comment'
            )
            notif.save()
```

> How about ***menu***? Like this stackoverflow, facebook, instagram, or else?

*you can handle it with templatetags, eg:*

```
# yourapp/templatetags/notification_tags.py

from django import template

from yourapp.models import Notification

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_unread_notif(user):
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=user, is_read=False)
    if notifications.exists():
        return True
    return False
```

and the `navs.html` menu:

```
{% load notification_tags %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <ul class="authenticated-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/notifications/">
          {% if request.user|has_unread_notif %}
            <i class="globe red active icon"></i>
          {% else %}
            <i class="globe icon"></i>
          {% endif %}
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need ManyToManyField for user module who is readed a post.

profile.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subscribed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed', blank=True)
readed = models.ManyToManyField("blogs.BlogPost", related_name='readed', blank=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.username)

class Meta:
    ordering = ("-created",)
```

If you have a blog model like this:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post_title = models.CharField("Post Title", max_length=150, unique=True)
post_content = models.TextField("Content")
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.post_title

class Meta:
    ordering = ("-created",)
```

You need to create a button function in blog posts view.

```
def mark_as_read_button(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    my_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    post = request.POST.get("post_pk")
    obj = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=post)

    if obj in my_profile.readed.all():
        my_profile.readed.remove(obj)
    else:
        my_profile.readed.add(obj)
    return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
return redirect("blogs:subscribed-blogs")
```

Then you can use is in the template file like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Subscribed Blog Posts{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.post_title }}</h5>
    {% if post in readed %}
        <form action="{% url "blogs:mark_as_read" %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_pk" value={{ post.pk }}>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Mark as unread</button>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        <form action="{% url "blogs:mark_as_read" %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_pk" value={{ post.pk }}>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Mark as read</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    <p class="card-text">{{ post.created }}</p>
    <p class="card-body">{{ post.post_content }}</p>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Good coding.